# problem in volume management in media player in android code

Tags: android, media-player, volume

I am working in an android tab which has tabs activities, I have made tab groups for every tabs, in one activity i have media player for playing audio song. everything is fine except 
i cann't control the volume of media player and I am not seeing volume control dialog of android device. here is my code,

```
mp=new MediaPlayer();
             mp.setWakeMode(getParent(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK); //for powermanagement
    try {
                if(GlobalConfig.notInternet==true)
                {
                     mp.setDataSource("/sdcard/abc/"+file);
                }else{
                    mp.setDataSource(url2);
                }
                mp.prepare();

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.start();
```

please help me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should be used to managing  media sound...

```
  AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

  //It gives max volume of ur device   

  int max_volume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

  //It gives current volume of device

   int current_volume=mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
   //Here you can set volume 
   int progress=your set value;
   mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,progress, 0);
```